# Measuring FLOPS and memory traffic in a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, profiling, profiler, perf

I am trying to profile a C++ program. For the first step, I want to determine whether the program is compute-bound or memory-bound by the [Roofline Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model). So I need to measure the following 4 things.

1. W: # of computations performed in the program (FLOPs)
2. Q: # of bytes of memory accesses incurred in the program (Byte/s)
3. π: peak performance (FLOPs)
4. β: peak bandwidth (Byte/s)

I have tried to use Linux perf to measure W. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335011/measuring-flops-of-an-application-with-the-linux-perf-tool/12342811#12342811), using `libpfm4`  to determine the available events (by `./showevinfo`). I found my CPU supports the `INST_RETIRED`event with umask `X87`, then I used `./check_events INST_RETIRED:X87` to find the code, which is `0x5302c0`. Then I tried `perf stat -e r5302c0 ./test_exe` and I got

```
 Performance counter stats for './test_exe':

        83,381,997      r5302c0

      20.134717382 seconds time elapsed

      74.691675000 seconds user
       0.357003000 seconds sys
```

Questions:

1. Is it right for my process to measure the W of my program? If yes, then it should be 83,381,997 FLOPs, right?
2. Why is this FLOPs not stable between repeated executions?
3. How can I measure the other Q, π and β?

Thanks for your time and any suggestions.

Comment: With `perf` that isn't more than a few years old, it has names for events like `perf stat -e task_clock,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,mem_load_retired.l1_miss` and so on, so you don't need numeric events or the `ocperf.py` wrapper.  Check `perf list`.  Also see [FLOPS in Python using a Haswell CPU (Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX))](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/107156857) for events like `fp_arith_inst_retired.128b_packed_double ` which actually counts flops (FMA counts as 2), if you multiply by the SIMD element count.

Comment: For bandwidth, you might want `intel_gpu_top -l` for a rough system-wide number from the memory controllers.  For theoretical max bandwidth, see benchmark results or Intel's specs.  For theoretical max FLOPS, see [FLOPS per cycle for sandy-bridge and haswell SSE2/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655835)

Comment: Thanks Peter! I am trying the FLOPS part. For bandwidth, I am just using CPUs but not GPUs.

Comment: I know you're not using the GPU.  Like I said, **system-wide** number from the memory controllers, which are shared by the CPU and GPU via the ring bus (or mesh on a Skylake-X).  The other columns of `intel_gpu_top` output are GPU-specific and thus irrelevant, but it is a handy way to see the system-wide read and write DRAM bandwidth in MB/s.  If  look at a baseline while the system is idle, that should tell you how much the iGPU is using for scan-out, if it's active at all.  (Plus interrupt handlers and whatnot.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for your comments. My GPU is NVIDIA GPU, can I use the method in the same way?

Comment: Did you try it?  If `intel_gpu_top` works at all, it will give you bandwidth numbers for the on-chip memory controllers on the CPU.  That's what I've told you 3 times now.