# Measuring CPU memory traffic during the execution of a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, memory, profiling, profiler

I want to measure the CPU memory traffic of a C++ program running on a Linux server. Because I know the the [theoretical maximum memory bandwidth](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056722/processors/intel-core-processors.html) of the server and I want to know how much memory bandwidth my program uses. It is regarding to memory traffic between DDR RAM and CPU. I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788336/measuring-flops-and-memory-traffic-in-a-c-program) which suggest to use `intel_gpu_top`. But the remote server doesn't have `intel_gpu_tools` and I don't have `sudo` permission. So I am wondering if there is any other suggestions to help me measure the CPU memory traffic. Thank you.

Comment: `which is denoted as the number of bytes of memory transfers incurred during the execution of the C++ program.` From where to where? Ram<->GPU? Network? RAM to cache?

Comment: Run your program with `time`. `$ time ./program`

Comment: @tkausl, I have edited the post. it is about RAM and CPU. I know from Intel that my CPU has a theoretical maximum memory bandwidth of over 50 GB/s and I just want to know how much memory bandwidth my program uses.

Comment: I'm not sure you can even measure this. The problem is shared L3 cache. Bandwidth used between L3 cache and main memory is not tagged with process IDs, AFAICT.

Comment: Depending on your CPU, there may be hardware performance counters that measure this.